# why is the integral of $e^{-x}/x = (x-1)e^{x}$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Why is $\int \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\; dx= (x-1)e^x$?

This is the answer in my calculus textbook, I thought that this was the form for an Exponential integral (which I know little about).

Therefore shouldn't the answer be something like:

$-E_1(x) + C$ ?

Comment: You are right. Also, $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (x-1)\exp x =x\exp x$.

Comment: Which textbook? Such an error (more than a simple typo) is not confidence inspiring. But you should be sure it's actually wrong. Note that the reciprocal of the integrand is $xe^x$. Was there anything else to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You can easily check on your own that the provided answer is incorrect by noticing that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)e^x=xe^x$$
which you can check by e.g. using the product rule, and this is obviously not the same as $e^{-x}/x$. The correct answer should be
$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=\operatorname{Ei}(-x)+C$$
for constant $C$, where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral.